# Python not printing out special characters (extracted from an html file) when I write to another html file

Tags: python, html, string, utf-8

I am extracting data from an html file and outputting it to another html file template using .replace. I wrote it so that on double clicking my script, the page opens up in a browser, ready to be printed.

Everything works fine until I ran into an extracted string that had a special character in it. On double click, nothing would happen (the web browser would not open). However, it seems to work when I run it straight from IDLE, with one issue: The special character comes up as a weird combination of characters.

I haven't tested this out with other special characters, but my problem right now is happening with Nyström, which comes up as NystrÃ¶m in my outputted file.

I figure this has something to do with encoding/decoding in 'utf-8', however I do not know enough about the subject to solve this issue myself post research.

When I open the read and write files, I make sure they have encoding='utf-8' as the third argument.

Finally, when I print the string i'm having trouble with out onto IDLE, it comes out fine. The issue just seems to pop up when I write it to my file.

Below are my file read and write calls if that helps

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
htmlFile = open(path + input_filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
htmlString = htmlFile.read()

infile = open(template_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
contents = infile.read()
```

After this I .replace certain parts of content with my extracted strings put into a dictionary named data.
eg:
(please ignore inconsistent naming conventions)

```
data = dict()
data['name_email'] = email    
contents = contents.replace('_name_email', data['name_email'])
```

then:

```
outfile = open(output_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
outfile.write(contents)
```

I am running this on python 3.6

Comment: When you read a file you must respect the encoding with which it was written.  Specifying utf-8 when opening a file doesn't magically convert a file written with a different encoding.  An HTML page can specify its encoding with the tag <meta charset=[xxx]>.  If that tag appears in your documents it will replace the default, which is indeed utf-8.  You might try opening the page containing "Nystrom" in a web browser and see what it looks like there.

Comment: Paul meant opening the web page in an editor, or simply right-click and View page source in (for instance) Firefox

Comment: I opened the file I am extracting from and from what I can tell it is indeed in UTF-8

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Try using a text editor to open and save your original html file in UTF-8. It could have been saved to disk using another encoding, despite the meta tag

Comment: When you say "which comes up as NystrÃ¶m in my outputted file", what application are you using to display the outputted file?  What encoding does it use?  In IDLE if you convert 'Nyström' to a bytearray using utf8, and decode it back to a string with latin1 (which I think is more-or-less 8-bit ASCII) you get NystrÃ¶m.  So the two strings are related.

Comment: Turns out my template file was in a different charset, which I fixed to be in UTF-8 and now the special character does come out, which is great.

However, the webpage is still not opening on double click, only via IDLE. It doesn't do this with other html files, just this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried deleting all of my print statements and that somehow did the trick. Either way thanks for the input guys